# What is the best way to gain back my question privileges

Tags: support, asking-questions

For reasons I will not say (let's just say that I made some mistakes), the askubuntu system took away my right to ask questions on the website. I have read that once I have a positive effect on the website, I could be able to ask questions again. Currently, I can reply to questions and provide answers to questions, and I have edited several questions from other people. Now, don't get me wrong, I'm not here to ask for you guys to manually allow me to ask questions (I have read on the website that you guys can't do that and there is no time-out for the ban). I'm just here (on ask ubuntu meta) to ask, how much does it take to gain back my question privileges?

Any help is appreciated.

P.S: This is the first time I have ever been on Ask Ubuntu Meta. I just discovered it on the Stack Exchange menu.

Comment: Let the auto block expire.  To get an asking ban you have to have done some nasty evils; best you can do is just wait

Comment: I thought there wasn't such thing as  a "timeout" for the ban.

Comment: I think there's multiple temporary ban levels but if you are permanently banned then you are out of luck

Comment: Well....I called someone a troll and said: "touchy touchy". Would that put me in a permanent ban???

Comment: You must of done a bit more than that, people have said things a lot worse and not been permanently banned. I doubt you are permanently banned from asking questions, as you can still answer and comment and your profile dose not say you are banned, plus you can post here too. Seems to me Thomas is correct and you just have to wait it out, likely for a week or so. Did you not receive an email or message outlining the criteria of the ban?

Comment: From the front page of [meta.se]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: No. I haven't seen any email. Well, I guess I'm just going to have to wait it out. Thank you guys so much for everything.

Comment: Well, now I've just remembered that I posted a "question" when I really was criticizing the askubuntu website. on that post, I falsely accused the same guy that I called a troll of serial-downvoting. The "question" or post was called: Askubuntu wasn't what I thought it was.  Now my question is: Is creating a "question" or a post that criticizes the askubuntu website and accusing someone of serial-downvoting guarantees the fact that I have a permanent ban?

Comment: No, but having 7 out of 10 questions deleted with a collective score of -13 does. I'm not sure you can work yourself out of that. None of them look salvageable. You are going to have to provide some stellar answers.

Comment: Oh and your other 3 questions are closed :/

Comment: I know that....

Comment: But am I doomed to a permanent ban?????

Comment: Am I??? Doomed to a permanent question ban?????? Can somebody please answer that for me????......

Comment: Well, I guess I will try to fix my questions and edit other people's questions as well. Thank you so much everyone.

Comment: Just FYI... there is a 200 daily rep cap. So you won't get any rep for edits after you've earned 200 that day.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ban is automatic based on the numbers attached to your posts (number closed, number deleted, downvotes, and — I believe — how closely together these things are time, among other numbers). It has nothing to do with anything you said, and there are no humans involved in placing *or* removing the ban. The ban doesn't care about anything you've written, only the numbers attached to what you've written. Specifically, the ban doesn't know and doesn't care if you've called anyone a troll.

The way to lift the ban is to improve your posts' numbers: fix your bad posts enough to get people to vote them up, post quality answers that get upvotes (since you're only question banned, not answer-banned), and generally improve your record. There's no formula to follow because the system's details are secret to prevent gaming it — just be a good site citizen in the ways you're not banned from, and the ban will go away eventually.

This is the short version of the longer version in the Stack Exchange FAQ:

> [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Do what it says, and that is how to undo the ban.

Comment: What happen if all of questions are closed. Which is currently my situation right now. I only had three questions before I got banned. I had others, but I had to delete them. My remaining three question are closed. What do I do now?

Comment: Answer questions. Fix your questions to get them reopened, if possible. Read the guide linked above.

Comment: Thanks you. I hope that I will no longer be under the ban hammer soon...

Comment: One more question.  Seth said above this: "No, but having 7 out of 10 questions deleted with a collective score of -13 does. I'm not sure you can work yourself out of that. None of them look salvageable. You are going to have to provide some stellar answers." Does this mean I might have gotten permanently banned from asking questions?????

Comment: @TheChosenOne99 As I said, the exact formula is secret, so we can't know for sure. You can only try. However, you are currently *not* answer banned, so if you know how to write quality answers you have potentially unlimited opportunity to counterbalance those numbers.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I guess I'm just going to have to wait and see. Thank you everyone for everything!

Comment: @TheChosenOne99 Actually, rather than waiting and seeing you might want to follow Seth's and SevenSidedDie's advice and editing your questions and post some answers.

Comment: Okay, I am starting there.